# Is there any closed-form for this integral?

Tags: integration

I have an expression

$$F(\theta)=h(N)+2\sum_{l=1}^{N-1}h(N-l)\cos(\theta l)$$

I want to find the integral of the following

$$\int_{\rm{lower}}^{\rm{upper}}(F(\theta))^2d\theta$$

here $\mathbf{h}$ is a vector of $N$ elements. $h(n)$ is the $n$-th element of $\mathbf{h}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, but for general limits you can't simplify it much: you expand the square, and use the trigonometric identities
$$
\cos{A}\cos{B} = \frac{1}{2} ( \cos{(A+B)} + \cos{(A-B)} )\\
\cos^2{A} = \frac{1}{2}(1+\cos{2A})
$$
(the second being a consequence of the first), and the integrals
$$ \int \cos{n\theta} \, d\theta = \frac{1}{n}\sin{n\theta} \\
\int \cos{n\theta}\cos{m\theta} \, d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n+m}\sin{(n+m)\theta}+\frac{1}{n-m}\sin{(n-m)\theta} & n \neq m \\
\theta+\frac{1}{2n}\sin{2n\theta} & n=m
\end{cases}. $$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you please see this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207192/how-to-find-the-integral-any-closed-form and suggest me a solution